# I'm unsure what to put in my try statement and I keep getting an "Ecxeption in thread "main"" error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Whenever I try and run my code, it gets to the firs two print statements before giving me an 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at templates.SentenceUtilsTest.main(SentenceUtilsTest.java:26)

I'm so lost, my professor hasn't explained try-catch statements, and this is a huge jump in difficulty from our previous assignment.

There is another class in the package.

```
package templates;

public class SentenceUtilsTest 
{

private static List<SentenceUtils> sList = new ArrayList<SentenceUtils>();


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("COP3330 Sentence Utility Program by [name]");
        System.out.println("\nInput file name: " + args[ 0 ] );

        try
        {
            File file = new File("cat.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            //insert code

            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am including the second class file in case that is an issue. We are supposed to scan the file from the other class, and put that into the strings in this class. Our last program did not have multiple classes and it was very briefly covered in class, and I am very lost and confused.

```
public class SentenceUtils 
{
  private String sentence;
  private String[] tokens;
  private String[] shingles;



public SentenceUtils( String s )
{
 sentence = s;
 generateTokens();
 generateShingles();
}

private void generateTokens()
{
  //code

}

 private void generateShingles()
 {
  //code
 }

 public void report()
 {
   //code
 }
}
```

The output is

```
---------------------------------------------------

COP3330 Sentence Utility Program by [name] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 
0 out of bounds for length 0
at templates.SentenceUtilsTest.main(SentenceUtilsTest.java:26)
```

The expected output is

```
---------------------------------------------------

COP3330 Sentence Utility Program by [name]

Input file name: [file name]
Number of sentences: [number]

Sentence 0 >

//The next parts are from the second class, specifically report()
The cat in the hat

Tokens:
0:The
1:cat
2:in
3:the
4:hat

Shingles:
//I have the logic for this laid out in my program, didn't think it 
//necessary to copy and paste though
```

Comment: What's frustrating is I have the logic laid out, but I can't figure out what the issue is and why I can't compile my code. I don't like to blame the professor, but he threw a lot at us with very little time to do it and very little explanation. And because of this issue, all the other code that works out how to get the "tokens" and the "shingles" won't matter and I will fail the assignment

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
 System.out.println("\nInput file name: " + args[ 0 ] );
```

You are unconditionally printing args[0].

The stack trace tells you that you can't print the first index (0) of an array that has length 0. It is that simple: an empty array doesn't have any index. `args` contains the arguments passed to the JVM when invoking your class. So unless you pass values to it, it is completely empty!

So, you either should pass at least one value to the application, or you would need some sort of check, like

```
if (args.length < whateverValueYouExcpect) {
  give error message
```

And lesson number 1: you don't try/catch exceptions that you do not **understand** (expect to happen)! Such exceptions are **bugs** in your code, you debug them, and fix the root cause.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very sorry to ask, would you be alright if I asked you how to fix it? What do I replace args[ 0 ] with? It's what our professor told us to put so I assumed that was the right thing to type.

Comment: @Luke See my updates. You should simply provide an argument to your class when invoking it, like `java SentenceUtilsTest Arg1 Arg2`. But please note: this place is  not a replacement for a tutor service. Please don't start "more questions via comments" ping pong. Beyond that, welcome to SO :-) ... and dont forget to accept helpful answers at some point ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I'm very sorry, I was just confused since our professor told us to type "System.out.println("\nInput file name: " + args[ 0 ] );"

Comment: @Luke that is alright, as said, simply accept at some point and move on to the next lesson ...